# Exponents and power series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm a CS major, and I'm learning about trees and time complexity.  I want to know if it always holds that b (the branching factor of a tree) to the power of d (the depth of the tree) is the sum of all prior levels plus 1.

More formally:
b^d = 1 + b^0 + b^1 . . . b^d-1

And whence comes the "1+" at the beginning?  Isn't that what b^0 is for*?  I can see a sort of pattern here, but the 1 throws me off.  Would calculus help me be a better programmer?  I loved my discrete mathematics curriculum -- is analysis related as well?

*i.e., is this why raising to the zeroth power = 1?

Comment: if $d$ is the depth of the tree, what is $n$?

Comment: Fixed, thanks.  I should probably just have stuck with x^n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true.  You are right that the starting 1 should not be there.  Then the sum of the [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) $b^0+b^1+\ldots +b^{n-1}=\frac {b^n-1}{b-1}.$  To see this, think of $b(b^0+b^1+\ldots +b^{n-1})=b^1+b^2+\ldots +b^{n}$, so $(b-1)(b^0+b^1+\ldots +b^{n-1})=b^n-1$

Comment: lol, okay, I'll think about it till I grok just what it means.  Thank you.

Comment: Wow yeah, that's interesting.  I can see that applies better and is more 'honest'.  Still don't know intuitively precisely why it holds, but thanks.

Comment: @bismuth:  try it with some small numbers:  $1+3+9+27=40=\frac {3^4-1}{3-1}$ or $1+5+25+125+625=781=\frac{5^5-1}{5-1}$

Comment: @bismuth:  I think the reason CS people run afoul of this is that they count by $2$'s so much.  Then the denomimator becomes $2-1=1$ and you can ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

If $b$ is a constant, then you can prove this using perturbation method as in Graham, Knuth, Patachnik 'Concrete Mathematics'. Denote $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}b^k$. Then,
$$
S_{n+1}=S_{n} +b^{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}b^k+b^{n+1}=b\sum_{k=0}^{n}b^k +1=bS_n+1
$$
From this it is easy to find that 
$$
S_n=\frac{1-b^{n+1}}{1-b}
$$
A special case of this when $|b|<1, n \to \infty$, then 
$$
S=\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n=\frac{1}{1-b}
$$